# VB.Net - How do I find the position of several elements in an array where a condition is met

Tags: vb.net

I'm a newbie programmer, and right now I'm creating a backgammon game in VB (a simple version right now which will be built up overtime).

I am trying to get the game to record how many checkers a player has, and where these checkers are on the board. The white checkers are represented as negative integers and black checkers as positive integers. Once this is done the player would be able to select which checker to move and where depending on their dice roll.

So my question is, how would I be able to record the element position in an array, for example, when the array is checked for values where the value is > 0 for the white checker player. I'll add my code for this section - sorry if my coding is poorly executed.

If possible dumb down the advice haha

```
Console.WriteLine("Make your first move: ")
For Each x In Gameboard
    If x > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} pieces in position ", x)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Also just a bit of context, this is for my Computer Science A-Level NEA project, once I have created the foundation of the game in VB i will be converting it to a c# project in a 2d unity game.

Comment: Yes, my gameboard is represented with a 1 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You could, create a counter variable, above your loop, and increment it in each iteration, but that's a bit ugly.  The preferable way to do it is to use a plain `For` loop, with a counter, rather than a `For Each` loop.  For instance:

```
Console.WriteLine("Make your first move: ")
For i As Integer = 0 To Gameboard.Length
    If Gameboard(i) > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} pieces in position {1}", Gameboard(i), i)
    End If
Next
```

General rule of thumb:

- If you need to know the index, use a `For` loop
- If you don't need to know the index, use a `For Each` loop

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, feel a bit stupid for asking the question, but i was stuck on that for a while so I figured I'd ask. I feel my code is going to be quite long-winded.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Fixed :)